# In SwiftUI, I used popover mode to present a page on pad, but there seems to be a bug in compact/regular transition

Tags: swiftui

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js5gm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYW9h.jpg)
The code is as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isPresented = true
        }, label: {
            Text("button click")
            .background(.green)
        })
        .popover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            EmptyView()
        })
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this

Comment: Why are you using an `EmptyView()` as the popover?

Comment: What is your question? Which compact/regular transition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.